# Trying to run a binary file while creating parent window in electronJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, electron, desktop-application

I am trying to execute a binary file in linux when an electron app is started. In development mode, everything is working properly, but when I build the app binary file (which is part of the app) is not executed.

**Here is the code where I`m executing the binary file:**

```
const { spawn, exec } = require('child_process');
const startServer = () => {
  const ls = exec('./binary');
  ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  });
  ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });
};

function createWindow() {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    icon: './electronJs.png',
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true,
    })
  );
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();
  startServer();
  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory path `./` is relative to generated executable file once packaged.
You should use `__dirname` to fully qualify your `binary` path and make it relative to the calling file.

```
const path = require('path')

const myexefilepath = path.join(__dirname, 'binary')

...

  const ls = exec(myexefilepath);
```

**If you use `asar` file format to package your app, previous solution won't work.**

Your options then are:

- Copy `binary` to the same folder where the generated executable file is.
- Use [`app.getPath( name )`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname) to get a path to a special directory where you can put your `binary`. My choice being `name: userData`

Comment: Thanks, man it is solved. I was stuck in there for about a day thanks to you it solved now.